# Java GUI GridBagLayout how to fit three combo box in one column?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am using Eclipse, programming in Java, using GridBagLayout layout manager for a school project.

So far it looks like this

[image]

I wanna put the three combo box (MM, DD, YYYY) in one column(aligned with accNoT and others) but I don't know how
I tried tinkering with weightx or weighty but I doesn't do anything

Here's the code to that portion

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
c.ipadx = 50;
pane.add(accNoT, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 1;
pane.add(cellNoT, c);



c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.weighty = 0.3;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 2;
pane.add(monthBox, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.weighty = 0.3;

c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 2;
pane.add(dayBox, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.weighty = 0.3;
c.gridx = 3;
c.gridy = 2;
pane.add(yearBox, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 3;
pane.add(planList, c);
```

I added some text in the image so it won't be a bit confusing
ps. I am following https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html
I just modified their example

So far what I did besides trying to figure out weightx and y which up till now I still don't understand
I put the DD and YYYY combo box in different column
Then I set some gridWidth to accNoT equals to 2 but it didn't work, the DD just disappeared

Comment: all the **other** components in the second column must have a constraint using 3 columns (`gridwidth = 3`) **do not forget** to set it to 1 for the DD, MM and YYYY fields  // `weightx` is used to *decide* how to distribute *unused* space among columns

Comment: should I add all the components in the second column wiith gridwidth = 3 except the three combo box?

Comment: Dear gawd it worked, Thank you so much, you're a legenddd

Comment: I'll be editing it out at  the question at what I did for references, just in case other begginers had this similiar problem

Comment: Whoops my bad will be editing it again

Answer (score 1):

ANSWERED THANK YOU SO MUCH user85421/////////////////////////////

Just like user85421 said in the comments, add gridwidth
the three combo box should be 1, then the rest should be 3

The code

```
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
c.ipadx = 50;
c.gridwidth = 3;
pane.add(accNoT, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 3;

pane.add(cellNoT, c);



c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 2;
c.gridwidth = 1;

pane.add(monthBox, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

//c.weighty = 0.3;

c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 2;
c.gridwidth = 1;
pane.add(dayBox, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

//c.weighty = 0.3;
c.gridx = 3;
c.gridy = 2;
c.gridwidth = 1;
pane.add(yearBox, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 3;
c.gridwidth = 3;
pane.add(planList, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 4;
c.gridwidth = 3;
pane.add(adjT, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 5;
c.gridwidth = 3;
pane.add(eUsageT, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 6;
c.gridwidth = 3;
pane.add(prevBAT, c);

////THIRD COLUMN//////////////////////////////////////////
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 4;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 3;
pane.add(monPLR, c);
```

The result

[image]

Yes it looks hideous but at least the three combo box fits in a column

You might notice in the "Third column" section 
The gridy =  4
That's because the YYYY combo box's gridy = 3

Once Again thank you user85421  for saving our group's lives